# registrar debezium conector en kafka conectar e iniciar el servicio

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Install kafka broker on a server, inside the config folder add the connector1.properties file where you add the connector configuration, which contains the specifications of another server that contains the database to be read, that is, the other server I just need the database.

create a directory called libs where you add another one that contains the connector debezium mysql, also configure the plugin.path of the file with connect-standalone.properties with the location of the directory that contains the connector.

I want to start the kafka connect service autonomously, that is, on a single server,
in turn I want to register a connector with this command

```
bin / connect-standalone.sh config / connect-standalone.properties connector1.properties
```

the properties of connector one are:

```
connector.class = io.debezium.connector.mysql.mysqlconnector
tasks.max = 1
database.hostname = (host port)
database.port = 3306
database.user = userdbz
database.password = 12345
database.include.list = sbsdigdb_migra
database.server.id = 184054
database.server.name = qaservermysql
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers = (ip): 6667
database.history.kafka.topic = sbsmigra
```

my `connect-standalone.properties` file

```
plugin.path = / usr / hdp / current / kafka-broker / libs / connect-plugins /
```

my problem lies in, when I want to run it it generates this error

```
(org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig: 279)
[2021-02-02 09: 01: 01,125] WARN The configuration 'offset.flush.interval.ms' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig: 287)
[2021-02-02 09: 01: 01,126] WARN The configuration 'key.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig: 287)
[2021-02-02 09: 01: 01,126] WARN The configuration 'offset.storage.file.filename' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig: 287)
[2021-02-02 09: 01: 01,126] WARN The configuration 'value.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig: 287)
[2021-02-02 09: 01: 01,126] WARN The configuration 'plugin.path' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig: 287)
[2021-02-02 09: 01: 01,126] WARN The configuration 'value.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig: 287)
[2021-02-02 09: 01: 01,126] WARN The configuration 'key.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig: 287)
[2021-02-02 09: 01: 01,127] INFO Kafka version: 2.0.0.3.1.4.0-315 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser: 109)
[2021-02-02 09: 01: 01,127] INFO Kafka commitId: 4243d589e2b33433 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser: 110)
[2021-02-02 09: 01: 01,153] WARN [AdminClient clientId = adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: 671)
```

Any kind of information would be of great help, I appreciate it

Comment: How are you deploying it? `Connection to node -1 could not be established` suggests a network issue and/or configuration problem

Comment: Do you mean "automatically" not "autonomously"? If so, you probably should be using systemctl to start connect-distributed, not connect-standalone

Comment: I mean autonomously I am only doing it on a server

Comment: I already added it to the problem description